# Rails / Simple Form - How to create a select box with HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

What's the best way to add a select box with options and default value using Simple Form and HAML?

This is my `_form.html.haml` content and `f.option` not working.

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|                                                                                                                                    
    = f.input :title       
    = f.input :body
    = f.label :category_id 
    = f.select :category_id, Category.all.map{|category| [category.name, category.id]}
    = f.option{value: "undefined"} 
    %br

= f.button :submit
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def get_select_data
    data = Category.all.map{ |category| [category.name, category.id] }
    data.push([.....])
  end
```

Probably put this in a service model.  Initialize the model in your controller, and use it in your view:

```
= f.select :category_id, @service_model.get_select_data
```

Perhaps this will be an ok start for you

Comment: But is't exist any way in client side(Haml) ?

Comment: That's what the collection attribute is for.  That type of logic isn't for the view.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of defining a select and a default value is:

```
= f.input :category_id, collection: Category.all.map{|category| [category.name, category.id]}, selected: 1
```

The `selected` attribute sets the id of the default item.

You can find more info about selects in Simple Form here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections